# Mobile Web: Remember Me Checkbox?

Tags: forms, login

For many desktop sites, the Remember Me checkbox is a very useful and important part of signing into a site. And, it is unchecked by default (there is a lot about this on several UX-based sites).

On Mobile Web, however, there is a stark disappearance of this feature. Researching this further I was unable to find any definitive sources as to why. I have some theories (a mobile phone is not the same as a computer terminal, which could be at work, a library, or home - it's in your pocket. Plus logging in via email is a PITA on mobile, but that shouldn't stop some from offering the option.).

Does anyone have any research that would justify the removal of this feature for Mobile Web? Sites like Facebook, Yelp, LinkedIn, ESPN, etc. remove it for Mobile Web. Many have it, however, for desktop. What's the "right" answer, and based on what evidence?

Comment: Its because a phone is a personal device used by 1 user but a computer isn't necessarily (ex work areas in libraries or apartment complexes). This means you can assume a mobile user wants to be remembered while you can not assume that for a pc.

Comment: @ClassicThunder that's where I was heading, too. I was surprised by the lack of any documentation and/or discussion on the topic anywhere (that I could find). There are a few sites that do it but most don't.

Comment: I guess for mobile, the industry is still torn between app based model and a responsive scaled down version of website as a model. In an app based one, the application remembers you. On the scaled down web one, you need a competent browser to handle that. It is only recently that Chrome, Dolphin and other such entities are providing a complete experience of data management. Even if they do, it is more fragmented. So I am not sure how the developers look at the mobile browser yet.

Comment: IMO it's a matter of security. If your cellphone was loaded with all your passwords (like, the banking one ...) and the cellphone is more exposed to theft or loss then it would be a real threat.  
The newer devices, with fingerprint readers might change the future of the mobile "remember me" thing.

Answer (score 2):

Removing "Remember Me" checkbox in login form on mobile devices is good practice, because pc or laptop may have many users, especially in developing countries, or at workplaces etc. Mobile phone is almost always personal and private device owned by one user. So instead of asking about remembering, we can (and should imho) remember user login status by default. It's made login form more lightweight and serve as smart default

Comment: This makes sense, and also remember, when you try to login on any website on mobile they ask you if you want the details to be remembered or not. So they give you the choice, but it comes after you put the details in. Which is fair.

Comment: I did this practise in my industrial mobile app and just today got a request to be able to clear the saved login information as the tablet they are using is shared between different people in the organization.  So now i'm looking for the best practice on how to display this.  Do I have a checkbox to save the info? (checkboxes on mobile are not good and are often too close to another element) or do I make a button to clear the saved login info!  I'm stressed cuz my login page looks so good right now and it won't after this!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this kind of question has a 'right' answer, but I can think of a couple of good reasons why it doesn't appear there.

For one, I can think of plenty of sites that **do** still have this functionality on mobile.  [Freelancer](http://freelancer.com) being the first example that jumps to mind.

It doesn't seem right to penalise a user for being on mobile, so in a good responsive design, typically this option should be offered on the mobile and tablet versions as well as the desktop.

It would seem to be the primary reason for not including this button is to encourage users not to use the mobile website - usually because they have an app as well.  In fact if you look at [Twitter](http://twitter.com), a site with no 'Remember Me' button, when you login, there's a sticky banner at the top, asking you to download the app.

A native app experience is usually better than a mobile website (there's a lot less browser 'chrome' to deal with for one), which would make sense in pointing the user to the app.  It's common knowledge that these days, [people are using apps more than ever](http://www.nielsen.com/us/en/insights/news/2015/so-many-apps-so-much-more-time-for-entertainment.html) and it seems that the preference is to drive people here - where they **will** remember your details by default, rather than the mobile web.

Of course, they still need to offer a mobile experience, but going back to my twitter comparison, looking at the Twitter website on an iPhone versus the Twitter app on an iPhone, there's a noticeable difference in terms of experience design.

In fact - the twitter 'heart' micro interaction sums up this difference.  Favourite a tweet on the mobile site, the star (favourite symbol), changes colour.  In the app there's an animated GIF - adding a moment of suprise and delight.